# Anchors Not Working In If Statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I've had a lot of trouble trying to fix this problem.
I have code that should activate if statements that change CSS when conditions in the anchor are met.
This is an example of the code:

```js
    window.setInterval(function() {
      var anchor = window.location.hash.slice(1);

      if (anchor = "Yellow") {
        $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
      }
      if (anchor = "White") {
        $("body").css("background-color", "white");
      }
    }, 0);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <a href="#Yellow">Yellow</a>
  <a href="#White">White</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Change `=` to `===` for a start.

Comment: ***As a side note*** You are firing an interval callback each 0 ms (well in fact 10-13ms), really?...  Whats wrong with hashchange event???

Answer (score 2):

### Variable comparison

Use `===` to check for equality inside `if` statements:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  var anchor = window.location.hash.slice(1);

  if (anchor === "Yellow") {
    $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
  }
  if (anchor === "White") {
    $("body").css("background-color", "white");
  }
}, 0);
```

When you do this:

```
if(anchor = "string")....
```

You're reassigning the `anchor` variable instead of checking its value.

---

### Event listening

As pointed out by [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) in his comment, you should use this instead of the `0ms` `timeout`:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){ // This function gets called everytime the has changes
  var anchor = window.location.hash.slice(1);

  if (anchor === "Yellow") {
    $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
  }
  if (anchor === "White") {
    $("body").css("background-color", "white");
  }
};
```

Look here for fallbacks for unsupported browsers: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use == or === comparison sign to check for if statements